# Moving react app created with create react app to another computer

Tags: reactjs

I used Create React App to create a React application on one computer.  No problem.  But how do I move the code to another computer (i.e. the entire folder structure) if I want to continue developing on another computer.  I have node installed and I have installed Create React App on the second computer (with the -g tag, etc.  But just moving the react application folders over to the second computer doesn't seem to work.  That is, npm start fails.  Any ideas?  It must be that I have to do something to the app on the second computer with Create React App.  What is it that I have to do?  I want to preserve and use my code on this second computer and continue developing (moving from Windows to Mac).  Thanks.

Comment: Copy everything except the `node_modules` folder. Then just run `npm install` on the other computer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. But this did not work.  Create React App is already installed on the second computer.  When I remove the node_modules folder, the  npm start command fails.  Why would I run npm install again?  Do I need to run Create React App in some way again.

Comment: Which errors do you get after copying everything over to the other computer?

Comment: $ npm start
> react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start /Users/andrewjoskow/React/react-complete-guide
> react-scripts start


sh: /Users/andrewjoskow/React/react-complete-guide/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Permission denied

code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
 Exit status 126
 Failed at the react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start script.
This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
A complete log of this run can be found in:
n /Users/andrewjoskow/.npm/_logs/2020-10-09T21_11_29_121Z-debug.log

Comment: Got this to work.  Remove both the `node_modules` folder AND the `package-lock.json` file.  THEN run `npm install` from the application folder.  THEN run `npm start`.

Answer (score 2):

there are some ways to copy your project to another computer

1. use git: you can use git hub to push your react project into a repository then you can clone that repository on another computer. note: use `npm install` after cloning the repository on another computer as it doesn't include node modules
2. share a compressed file: you can compress your react app folder and transfer it to another computer extract it to use it

Answer (score 0):

Use git.
you can use git to upload project, then unload project on a second computer, create a branch and continue working.
After unloading, you need to run the `npm install` command.

Answer (score 0):

Git is your easiest solution. Upload to git hub from the current laptop. Then on the new laptop, download the file (zip) and run npm install. Once everything works locally you can publish to a new branch on github in the initial repository.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).